# How to detect if the image is panoramic in React Native?

Tags: image, react-native, 360-panorama

I am working on image picker functionality in React Native. I am using react-native-image-crop-picker npm package. Now, there is requirement to pick Panoramic images from the gallery. How can I detect if the image is Panoramic or not? On the basis of this, I want to show image in Panoramic View(I have already implemented this functionality).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to tell the difference between a not phanora and a phanora from the gallery. There is no such function at the moment, and what the gallery separates is something that the client cannot do.

But what I can suggest is that after selecting a picture, you can know the width and height of the picture when you receive the response value. I think you can tell if it's panoramic at this value.

**Generic Image Size**

[image: generic]

**Panoramic Picture Size**

(nonmal)
(width: 4912 × 1080)
(height: 3424 × 1920)
Take the image to the standard size.

(wide)
(width: 7152 × 1080)
(height: 4912 × 1920)
Take the image in wide size.

(360°)
(가로: 11520 × 1080)
Use 360 degrees to strobe the image.

(highpixel)
(가로: 10480 × 4096)
43 megapixels for high-resolution panoramas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any particular difference between the dimensions of panoramic image and normal image?

Comment: I wrote a comparison of the size of a generic image and a panoramic image in the answer. Please reference.

Comment: Thanks, but I saw 360 images with 724*328 resolution as well.

Comment: It would be hard to tell apart if there is such an image. I think there is an error in my idea. This problem is unlikely to be solved unless the gallery is approached by a client and is authorized to change it.